# Cross browser event propagation behaviour when event target removed from DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-browser

We are having a cross-browser issue with the behaviour of Bootstrap-enhanced anchors that contain a span. Having looked at the Bootstrap js, I've managed to distill the problem down to the following code (this has no dependency on Bootstrap):

HTML:

```
<a href="http://doc.jsfiddle.net">
    <span>Glyph</span> Download
</a>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', 'a', function () {
        var $anchor = $(this)
        $anchor['html']('Downloading');        
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VV767/1/

In IE 10 clicking within the `span` (with the text "Glyph"), the link through to the anchor URL is suppressed. Clicking anywhere else within the anchor (i.e. the text "Download") and the link is activated (the desired behaviour). In Chrome 32, clicking anywhere in the anchor (both in and out of the `span`) and the anchor URL is correctly activated. I've not tested Firefox.

The js code, which is simplified from Bootstrap's [`button.js`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/button.js) code, switches the anchor content to a "Downloading" text when clicked. (Here's an actual example using Bootstrap: http://jsfiddle.net/M4DuJ/10/. Clicking the glyph in IE 10 will not activate the link).

The problem appears to originate from the fact the event target, the `span`, is being removed from the DOM when replaced with the text "Downloading" (in `button.js` the original html anchor content is stored using the jquery `data()` api, so you can reset it a later point).

My question is whether this is a known issue/quirk and if there is a more elegant/simplified solution to the one I have provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment we have this workaround:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a > span', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    var $anchor = $(this).parent();
    var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    e.initEvent('click', true, true);
    $anchor[0].dispatchEvent(e);
});
```

That is to intercept the click on the `span`, prevent the event propagation, and then invoke the click on the parent anchor. This works in Chrome 32 and IE 10.

http://jsfiddle.net/87KXy/

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are looking for a workaround that’s a little less inelegant (is it? might lay in the eye of the beholder), I’d go for something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $anchor['html']('Downloading');
        window.location.href = $anchor.attr('href');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VV767/3/

It’s a little more direct way of navigating to the link target, and spares you creating and dispatching an event …

Caveat: This’ll only work if the link’s target is the same window. Inside a frame environment it might be amended to change the location of another frame by reading the links target attribute first; if the target is `_blank` however, it might involve opening a new window and that might be prevented by the popup blocker.